# How to add a UIImageView of specific size programmatically in objective-c. I also have a xib file for the same class but i donot want to use it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xib, programmatically-created

How to add a UIImageView of specific size programmatically in objective-c.

I also have a xib file for the same class but i donot want to use it

I have written following code in ***viewDidLoad*** method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *dot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,30,30,50)];
    dot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"personal_info.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:dot];
}
```

Comment: ok , what happens next ?

Comment: What exactly you want. With above you should get UIImagaeView on your View. If you are not seeing ImageView then check your resource `personal_info.png` present or not ?

Comment: try `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:dot];` just to make sure it isn't covered by another object on screen

Comment: I added this line of code also ([self.view bringSubviewToFront:dot];)

Comment: I  added this line of code also ([self.view bringSubviewToFront:dot];) but still i cannot see the imageview and image is also present in the  supporting files. I am having a xib file linked to this viewcontroller, what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check that image name is correct, case sensitivity issues can cause this. If that not the case, please put a break point in viewwillAppear method and check the ui hierarchy using view debugger. [please go through this link to know about view debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html). make sure that the image view you have added is present in view hierarchy. Hope this will help you.